Scroll from section to section with variable height using gsap
I want to implement a site with scrolling from section to section (with a height equal to the height of the screen) using a gsap.to, provided that there are sections whose height can be either less or greater than the height of the screen. In general, it is somewhat similar to FullPage, but I don’t quite like its functionality and how it works in general. I made an example in CodePen.
JS part
const sections = $("section");
const sectionContents = $("section > div");

let currentSectionIndex = 0;
let isScrolling = false;
let isTouching = false;

$(document).on("wheel", handleWheel);
$(document).on("touchstart", handleTouchStart);
$(document).on("touchmove", handleTouchMove);
$(document).on("touchend", handleTouchEnd);

let touchStartY = 0;
let touchStartTime = 0;

function handleTouchStart(event) {
  console.log('handleTouchStart - is on');
  isTouching = true;
  touchStartY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;
  touchStartTime = Date.now();
}

function handleTouchMove(event) {
  console.log('handleTouchMove - is on');
  if (!isTouching) return;
  event.preventDefault();
}

function handleTouchEnd(event) {
  console.log('handleTouchEnd - is on');
  isTouching = false;
  const touchEndY = event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].clientY;
  const touchEndTime = Date.now();

  const deltaY = touchEndY - touchStartY;
  const deltaTime = touchEndTime - touchStartTime;

  const velocity = Math.abs(deltaY / deltaTime);

  // Check cur section
  const currentSection = sections.eq(currentSectionIndex);
  const contentHeight = currentSection.find("> div").prop("scrollHeight");
  const windowHeight = $(window).height();

  if (contentHeight > windowHeight) {

    scrollInSection(currentSection, deltaY);
  } else {
    if (velocity > 1) {
      // High velocity, scroll quickly
      scrollInSection(currentSection, deltaY);
    } else {
      // Low velocity, scroll slowly
      scrollToSection(currentSection);
    }
  }
}

function handleWheel(event) {
  // console.log('handleWheel - is on');
  event.preventDefault();

  if (isScrolling) return;
  isScrolling = true;

  const deltaY = event.originalEvent.deltaY;
  const direction = deltaY > 0 ? "down" : "up";

  const targetSection = sections.eq(currentSectionIndex);

  // Check if the current section has a large content
  if (targetSection.hasClass("large-content")) {
    scrollInSection(targetSection ,deltaY, direction);
  } else {
    if (direction === "down") {
      currentSectionIndex = Math.min(currentSectionIndex + 1, sections.length - 1);
    } else {
      currentSectionIndex = Math.max(currentSectionIndex - 1, 0);
    }

    scrollToSection(sections.eq(currentSectionIndex));
  }
}

function scrollInSection(targetSection, deltaY, direction) {
  console.log('scrollInSection - to ' + targetSection.attr('class'));
  const windowHeight = $(window).height();
  const sectionContent = targetSection.find("> div");
  const currentScrollTop = sectionContent.scrollTop();
  const sectionHeight = sectionContent.prop("scrollHeight");
  const sectionVisibleHeight = windowHeight / 3; 
  let targetScrollTop;

  const isAtTop = currentScrollTop === 0;
  const isAtBottom = currentScrollTop + windowHeight === sectionHeight;

  if ((isAtTop && deltaY < 0 && direction === "up") || (isAtBottom && deltaY > 0 && direction === "down")) {
    isScrolling = false;
    return;
  }

  if (deltaY > 0) {
    targetScrollTop = Math.min(currentScrollTop + sectionVisibleHeight, sectionHeight - windowHeight);
  } else {
    targetScrollTop = Math.max(currentScrollTop - sectionVisibleHeight, 0);
  }

  sectionContent.stop().animate({ scrollTop: targetScrollTop }, 500, function() {
    isScrolling = false;
  });
}

function scrollToSection(targetSection) {
  console.log('scrollToSection to ' + targetSection.attr('class'), targetSection.height(), $(window).height());
  const targetY = targetSection.offset().top;

  // Scroll to the next section
  gsap.to(window, {
    duration: 1.7,
    scrollTo: {
      y: targetY
    },
    onComplete: function() {
      isScrolling = false;
    }
  });
}

Here section_4 has a large height, and upon reaching this section everything works fine, but when scrolling back everything breaks...
What am i doing wrong?

scrollInSection seems to be breaking it. Specifically, once you start scrolling within #section6. My guess is that you would need to check if you have left he tall sections, and then reapply the scrollToSection.
